# passing strings to another class into a query

Tags: java, string, class, google-analytics-api

So here is my question to all the JAVA experts. I am trying to pass a string that i am getting from a properties file into another class which is a query. Sorry if this seems really basic...i really have no idea how to do it. Here is what i have so far

```
    public class CrunchifyGetPropertyValues {

    public String getPropValues() throws IOException {

        //some code...

        // get the property value and print it out
        String user = prop.getProperty("user");
        String startDate = prop.getProperty("startDate");
        String endDate = prop.getProperty("endDate");
        String values = prop.getProperty("values");

        result = "stuff = " + startDate + ", " + endDate + ", " + values;
        System.out.println(result + "\nProgram Ran on " + time + " by user=" + user);
        return result;
    }

    //this is the code that i thought i needed to connect the strings
    executeDataQuery startConv = new executeDataQuery();
    startConv.executeDataQuery(startDate);
}
```

here is my query that i am trying to put the string into

```
    private static GaData executeDataQuery(Analytics analytics, String profileId, String newValueData) throws IOException {
    return analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileId, // Table Id. ga: + profile id.
         newValue Data, // Start date: here is where i want to import the strings into
        "2014-05-20", // End date.
        "ga:pageviews,ga:sessions,ga:uniquePageviews") // Metrics.
        .setDimensions("ga:date")
        .setSort("-ga:date")
        .setMaxResults(25)
        .execute();
}
```

EDIT: 
so i've changed some stuff around but my code just took me to a new error to here...

```
try {
  httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
  dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
  Analytics analytics = initializeAnalytics();
  String profileId = getFirstProfileId(analytics);
  String newStringValue = getPropValues();
  if (profileId == null) {
    System.err.println("No profiles found.");
  } else {
    GaData gaData = executeDataQuery(analytics, profileId, newStringValue);
    printGaData(gaData);
  }
//lots of other code
```

Where i put in String new StringValue = getPropValues()...it says that the method was not able to be defined...any help?

Comment: When you say `System.out.println(myString);` you are passing a string to another class.  What specifically is special about your situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extent your signature (second method's 'head') to:
`private static GaData executeDataQuery(Analytics analytics, String profileId, String newStringValue) throws IOException {` and use `newStringValue` in there.

In the first code just call `executeDataQuery(first, second, newStringValue)`.

Comment: ok i changed the signature of the executeDataQuery to call an additional string but it took me to another spot where i guess i need to change some data around i put another example in my post

Comment: Most likely the compiler says there is no `executeDataQuery` taking three parameters. Did you changed the method's signature as well? In that case the compiler shall find the method...